# UnsafePointer no longer works in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

After I convert from swift 2 to swift 3, there is an error pop up for the below metioned line

```
let value = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(array1).pointee
```

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

in swift2 it is like

```
let value = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(array1).memory
```

Can someone explain please?
Sorry I'm quite new to swift3

After i have make the changes to

```
let abc = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(array1).withMemoryRebound(to: <#T##T.Type#>, capacity: <#T##Int#>, <#T##body: (UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) throws -> Result##(UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) throws -> Result#>)
```

but still what value should go in to the variable? Sorry, i have search around but too bad i can't find a solution

Comment: `Results from C functions that return nullable pointers must be explicitly unwrapped before accessing the pointee property (formerly memory) or subscript elements. Optional chaining syntax works well here, e.g. result?.pointee = sum.`

May this helps...https://swift.org/migration-guide/

Comment: Please show what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What type is the `array1`？ `UnsafeRawPointer`？

Comment: @LinShiwei var array1 = [UInt8](count4: repeated 0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let rawPointer = UnsafeRawPointer(array1)
let pointer = rawPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)
let value = pointer.pointee
```

Raw pointer is a pointer for accessing untype data.

`assumingMemoryBound(to:)` can convert from an `UnsafeRawPointer` to `UnsafePointer<T>`.

Reference :[Swift 3.0 Unsafe World](http://technology.meronapps.com/2016/09/27/swift-3-0-unsafe-world-2/?utm_source=tuicool&utm_medium=referral)

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is an `Array`, your best bet is to use `withUnsafeBufferPointer`:

```
array.withUnsafeBufferPointer { buffer in
    // do something with 'buffer'
    // (if you need an UnsafePointer rather than an UnsafeBufferPointer,
    // you can access that via the buffer's .baseAddress property)
}
```

Make sure you don't let the buffer pointer escape from the closure, because it will not be valid outside it.