# Xcode 10 Swift 3 or 4.2 has no member 'bindMemory'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

i have old project this was work well bu i am update my  xcode it give this error swift version 3, 4, 4.2 in all swift version same error

> Value of type 'UnsafePointer<_>' has no member 'bindMemory'

```
public convenience init(data: Data) throws {
let buffer = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.bindMemory(to: Int8.self) }
try self.init(buffer: buffer)
}
```

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824340/unsafepointer-no-longer-works-in-swift-3

Comment: any other  idea ?